# Monopoly: The Mega Edition Bankruptcy rule for distribuiting properties of creditor

Tags: monopoly-mega-edition

Lets suppose player "A" goes bankrupt to player "B".

B owns 3 properties of red color and has built hotels on each of them.

A has the 4th property and it goes to B as part of bankruptcy.

1. Should B evenly distribute the hotels / houses on all 4 of the red colored properties.

Suppose if A had that property mortgaged
2. Should B unmortgage it and distribute the hotels/houses on all 4 of them?

Comment: You've tagged this with five completely different Monopoly games with completely different rules and gameplay to each other. Which monopoly game are you asking about?

Comment: The edit to the question makes it answerable.

Comment: Monopoly mega edition

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must un-mortgage the property and redistribute the building across all the properties.
[Rules](https://www.winning-moves.com/images/megamonopolyrules.pdf)

Owning all but one

> You may build houses and hotels once you
>   own all but one property in a color group

Accruing the last one

> If you acquire the
>   final property of a group, after previously building on its other
>   properties, you must un-mortgage this property immediately
>   (if mortgaged) and build it up according to the “even” building rule or, if you can’t afford to do so, you must redistribute
>   existing houses among all properties of the group. You may
>   need to break down hotels to do this

Comment: When it says "you may need to break down hotels" does it mean you can treat the hotel as if it were five houses and spread them out over the properties, or do you have to sell the hotel and then spread the four houses out? And what happens if there is a building shortage and no houses left? Are you forced to simply sell all three hotels entirely?

Comment: @Showsni That is what the rules say but I am guessing you have to sell the hotel and get 4 houses in return. Also if there are not enough houses I assume you have to keep selling until there are enough in stock to make it even.